# How to fix \min in beamer?

Tags: beamer, math-operators

If I use `\min` in a regular document, it shows correctly:

[image]

However, if I use the same command in a beamer presentation I get:

[image]

Here's my header:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %no nav symbols
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

For the moment I defined a new operator, namely,

```
\def\Min{\operatornamewithlimits{min\vphantom{p}}}
```

but I really would like to know why `\min` doesn't work.

Comment: Please, post the minimal code to produce that error.

Comment: The same? In particular h_\vartheta changed into f(\vartheta,\mathbb{x})\neq y? Amazing! ;-) And seriously: please enlarge this to a MWE.

Comment: what are you using \usepackage[spanish]{babel} for? try remove it, and clear everything but the tex file, recompile.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Did you try with `mathptmx` instead of `times`?

Answer (score 1):

In the preamble, you load a Times-based *text* font, but no corresponding math font. Interestingly, loading either the [mathptmx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) or the [txfonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) package -- which provide both text *and* math fonts -- doesn't help. However, loading either the [newtxmath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx) or the [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package, along with a Times *text* font package such as `newtxtext`,  does the job.

First, the outcome with the `newtxmath` package loaded; note that it's necessary to insert a thinspace, i.e., `\,`, after `\bigl(` in order to avoid a collision with the subsequent `f`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %no nav symbols
}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,verbatim}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\min_{h_{\theta}\in\mathcal{H}} P_{\mathcal{D}} 
   \bigl(\, f(\theta,\mathbf{x})\ne y \bigr)
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Second, the result with `mtpro2` loaded instead of `newtxmath` -- note that it's no longer necessary to insert a thinspace between `\left(` and `f`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %no nav symbols
}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,verbatim}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\min_{h_{\theta}\in\mathcal{H}} P_{\mathcal{D}} 
   \bigl( f(\theta,\mathbf{x})\ne y \bigr)
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A final note: The full [mtpro2 package](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) isn't free of charge. However, its "lite" subset, which is all that's required for this example, *is* free of charge.